# Get the end time using start time and duration values

Tags: typescript, momentjs

How to calculate end time using start time and duration?

I have an API that will send me the values as below

```
data : {
'startTime': 1100,    // (this will be 24hrs format i.e 11:00 AM)
'duration' : 60      // (in mins)
}
```

Now, using these above attributes, I should calculate the end time like 11:00 AM + 60 = 12:00 PM

Comment: Was this a invalid question ?? I dont understand here.

Comment: You need to at least have a go at proposing an API and some logic!. What's your duration in, how do you handle date logic. How would you handle adding a date with a duration in seconds, minutes, hours, etc? We're here to help if you get stuck, not to help you do your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = {
   'startTime': 1100,    // (this will be 24hrs format i.e 11:00 AM)
   'duration' : 60      // (in mins)
}
const result = moment(data.startTime, 'HHmm').add(data.duration, 'minute').format('HH:mm A');
```